# Question deleted after answer

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

Earlier today I answered a question titled "About the paper : “Label-Free Supervision of Neural Networks with Physics and Domain Knowledge”", for which I had to check the original paper. I spent some time answering the question but then, half an hour later the user deleted his question and there goes my answer with it. I do not mind getting no votes or getting downvoted, but information being deleted so easily is quite annoying.

My question is, isn't there some kind of restriction on deleting answered questions so easily? If there is not, can I block the user so that I won't spend any more time trying to answer questions from him?

Comment: Apologies.  I did a search but I can't find the question.  (Link in you can--sometimes they remain searchable.)

Comment: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/about-the-paper-label-free-supervision-of-neural-networks-with-physics-and-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are restrictions. For example, you cannot delete a question with more than one answer or with an upvoted or accepted answer. See [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/287113) for more info. Apparently, your answer wasn't upvoted.

Regarding the "block a user" feature, see [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/287113).

I understand your feelings now, given that you spent time to provide a good answer and information. However, I would advise you not to give much importance to this episode. It may happen, but this usually does not happen!

Comment: Follow up: Isn't there supposed to be a time limit for that? I mean the question itself had 2 upvotes (if I am not mistaken), so those people probably would be interested in learning the answer but they probably never had a chance to see it. And any restriction on the number of question a user can delete in a given period of time?

Comment: @serali After having quickly skimmed through the linked answer, it seems there is no time limit or restriction. If there was a link to such a question, I would see it, but I don't have the link to it. I suggest you read https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/287113 for more info.

Comment: Do you think the question does any harm, because I can undelete it...

Comment: @DukeZhou After having read it, I don't think that the question can harm anyone, apart from the original poster (that is, the OP deleted it for some reason, I suppose). I would undelete it and ask the OP for clarifications regarding its deletion. I can also undelete it, btw, but I only noticed now that the link to the question has been provided.

Comment: I went ahead and undeleted b/c in this case, the deletion was unfair to the responder.